# The requested URL /customer/account/login/ was not found on this server

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-account, core-config-data, base-url

How to solve this issue, If I manually add index.php it is working.

```
mydomain.com/index.php/customer/account/login/  -- works

mydomain.com/customer/account/login/ -- not working
```

my base url in core_config_data is  http://www.mydomain.com/

Comment: Is index.php set as the default file in your Apache configuration?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

> turn off url rewriting from magento admin configuration>web> Search
>   Engines Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites > No

```
RewriteEngine  comment this line in In your .htaccess in the root of your installation
```

Answer (score 2):

1. As I know magento already provide `.htaccess` under `<httpd DocumentRoot>/magento`, assume Magento was installed to this directory, the `.htaccess` provide directives to turn `RewriteEngine` and provide `RewriteRule`
2. What you need to do is make sure `mod_rewrite` is uncommented and `AllowOverride` is given `All` in httpd conf file, e.g. `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to make sure `.htaccess` overriding works

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blogpost on this which should help you http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/05/26/magento-remove-index-php-from-url/

Basically you need apache mod_rewrite module and setting in Magento which will rewrite the URLs. You will get step-by-step instruction on above link.

Comment: Thanks, I have done as said there but am missing the .httaccess file what could be done for that ?

Comment: @NishanthLawrence get the `.htaccess` file from a clean magento instance and add it to your instance.

Comment: @Marius I have copied the .htaccess from a new magento instance, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @NishanthLawrence Then are you absolutely sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server and you set `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` on the document root?

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite in enabled .. How to set Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  ??

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess in the root of your installation (i.e. the directory that contains app, skin etc folders), add this line at the bottom

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

ReWrites must be ON btw. i.e. see that the .htaccess file executes the line below before any RewriteRule is executed.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Once you've made and committed these changes in your .htaccess, the problem should be hopefully solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento ***Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization***, change the value of Web Server Rewrites to No